# Format dates from a JSON array to time only

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a column with values of an array queried with `JSON_QUERY`.

Result Set will look like this:

My_Column

```
["2017-06-13T07:00:00","2017-06-13T12:00:00","2017-06-13T17:00:00"]  

["2017-05-04T06:00:00","2017-05-04T16:00:00","2017-05-04T23:00:00"]  

["2017-05-04T04:00:00","2017-05-04T11:00:00","2017-05-04T16:00:00"]  

["2017-05-04T07:00:00","2017-05-04T12:00:00","2017-05-04T17:00:00"]  

["2017-05-26T08:00:00","2017-05-26T12:00:00","2017-05-26T16:00:00","2017-05-26T20:00:00"]
```

How to format the column in order to retrieve only the times separated by a comma?

My_Column

```
00:00, 12:00, 17:00  
06:00, 16:00, 23:00  
04:00, 11:00, 16:00
```

and so on

Comment: In 5th row, are there 4 dates stored?

Comment: Yes, there can be several values in that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user defined function (UDF) that performs the conversion:

```
if object_id('FxJsonDateConverter') is not null
    drop function FxJsonDateConverter
go

create function FxJsonDateConverter(@serializedDateTime varchar(max))
    RETURNS varchar(max) AS
    BEGIN
        declare @result varchar(max) = ''
        declare @dates table(json_date time)

        insert into @dates
        select CONVERT(time,[value]) 
        from string_split(replace(replace(replace(@serializedDateTime, '"',''), ']',''), '[',''),',')

        select @result =   @result +  ', '+ left(cast(json_date as varchar(max)),5) 
        from @dates
        return RIGHT(@result, len(@result)-2)
    end
go

declare @your_table table (your_column varchar(max))

insert into @your_table
 values
('["2017-06-13T07:00:00","2017-06-13T12:00:00","2017-06-13T17:00:00"]'  ),
('["2017-05-04T06:00:00","2017-05-04T16:00:00","2017-05-04T23:00:00"]'  ),
('["2017-05-04T04:00:00","2017-05-04T11:00:00","2017-05-04T16:00:00"]'  ),
('["2017-05-04T07:00:00","2017-05-04T12:00:00","2017-05-04T17:00:00"]'  ),
('["2017-05-26T08:00:00","2017-05-26T12:00:00","2017-05-26T16:00:00","2017-05-26T20:00:00"]' )

select your_column, dbo.FxJsonDateConverter(your_column) as only_time 
from @your_table
```

Results:

[image]